# Why is there segmentation fault(core dumped) in my multithreaded scheduling program in C

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads, scheduling

I have to write a multi-threaded program in C in which one thread displays working of FCFS Scheduling and the other shows SJF scheduling. Now if I run the two types of scheduling  as separate C programs, I get no errors and the programs run smoothly. But when I put them in two different functions and use the concept of multi-threading, the terminal prints the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" Please help me out

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *fcfs(void *);
void *sjf(void *);
int pid[10],at[10],bt[10];
int pid1[10],at1[10],bt1[10];
void main()
{
    pthread_t fcfsT,sjfT;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int lower = 0, upper = 20, count = 10;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pid[i]=i+1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        at[i] = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
        bt[i] = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pid1[i]=pid[i];
        at1[i]=at[i];
        bt1[i]=bt[i];
    }
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_create(&fcfsT,&attr,fcfs, NULL);
    pthread_create(&sjfT,&attr,sjf,NULL);
    pthread_join(fcfsT,NULL);
    pthread_join(sjfT,NULL);
}

void *fcfs(void *p)
{
    int ct[10],a,wt[10],tat[10],i,j=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            if (at[i] > at[j]) 
            {
                a =  at[i];
                at[i] = at[j];
                at[j] = a;
                a =  bt[i];
                bt[i] = bt[j];
                bt[j] = a;
                a =  pid[i];
                pid[i] = pid[j];
                pid[j] = a;
             }
         }
    }
    ct[0]=at[0]+bt[0];
    for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(at[i]<ct[i-1])
            ct[i]=ct[i-1]+bt[i];
        else
            ct[i]=at[i]+bt[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    {
         for (j = i + 1; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            if (pid[i] > pid[j]) 
            {
                a =  pid[i];
                pid[i] = pid[j];
                pid[j] = a;
                a =  at[i];
                at[i] = at[j];
                at[j] = a;
                a =  bt[i];
                bt[i] = bt[j];
                bt[j] = a;
                a =  ct[i];
                ct[i] = ct[j];
                ct[j] = a;      
             }
         }
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        tat[i]=ct[i]-at[i];
        wt[i]=tat[i]-bt[i];
    }
    printf("PID\tAT\tBT\tCT\tTAT\tRT:\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("P%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",pid[i],at[i],bt[i],ct[i],tat[i],wt[i]);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

void *sjf(void *g)
{
    int ct1[10],b,wt1[10],tat1[10],z,q=0,minimum,location,temp[3]={0,0,0};
    for (z = 0; z < 10; ++z) 
    {
         for (q = z + 1; q < 10; ++q)
        {
            if (bt1[z] > bt1[q]) 
            {
                b =  bt1[z];
                bt1[z] = bt1[q];
                bt1[q] = b;
                b =  at1[z];
                at1[z] = at1[q];
                at1[q] = b;
                b =  pid1[z];
                pid1[z] = pid1[q];
                pid1[q] = b;
             }
         }
    }

    for (z = 0; z < 10; ++z) 
    {
        for (q = z + 1; q < 10; ++q)
        {
            if (bt1[z] == bt1[q]) 
            {
                if(at1[q]<at1[z])
                {
                    b =  bt1[z];
                    bt1[z] = bt1[q];
                    bt1[q] = b;
                    b =  at1[z];
                    at1[z] = at1[q];
                    at1[q] = b;
                    b =  pid1[z];
                    pid1[z] = pid1[q];
                    pid1[q] = b;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    minimum = at1[0];
    for ( z = 1 ; z < 10 ; z++ ) 
    {
        if ( at1[z] < minimum ) 
        {
           minimum = at1[z];
           location = z;
        }
    }
    temp[0] = at1[location];
    temp[1] = bt1[location];
    temp[2] = pid1[location];
    for(z=location;z>0;z--)
    {
        at1[z]=at1[z-1];
        bt1[z]=bt1[z-1];
        pid1[z]=pid1[z-1];
    }
    at1[0]=temp[0];
    bt1[0]=temp[1];
    pid1[0]=temp[2];
    ct1[0]= at1[0]+bt1[0];
    for(z=1;z<10;z++)
    {
        if(at1[z]>ct1[z-1])
            ct1[z] = at1[z]+bt1[z];
        else
            ct1[z] = bt1[z]+ ct1[z-1];
    }
    for (z = 0; z < 10; ++z) 
    {
         for (q = z + 1; q < 10; ++q)
        {
            if (pid1[z] > pid1[q]) 
            {
                b =  pid1[z];
                pid1[z] = pid1[q];
                pid1[q] = b;
                b =  at1[z];
                at1[z] = at1[q];
                at1[q] = b;
                b =  bt1[z];
                bt1[z] = bt1[q];
                bt1[q] = b;
                b =  ct1[z];
                ct1[z] = ct1[q];
                ct1[q] = b;

             }
         }
    }
    for(z=0;z<10;z++)
    {
        tat1[z]=ct1[z]-at1[z];
        wt1[z]=tat1[z]-bt1[z];
    }
    printf("pid1\tAT\tBT\tCT\tTAT\tRT:\n\n");
    for(z=0;z<10;z++)
    {
        printf("P%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",pid1[z],at1[z],bt1[z],ct1[z],tat1[z],wt1[z]);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Now is the time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Also note that the C specification says that the `main` function must be declared to return an `int`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude still its giving the same error!

Comment: Not sure it is the cause of the problem, but `attr` is not initialised. Please turn on all compiler warnings.

Comment: There is a bunch of things wrong. It starts with use of globals, which makes things more complicated in particular in a multithreaded environment. Then, use of "magic numbers". Then, if you have multiple arrays with the same size and where elements correspond to each other, it's often clearer to use a single array of `struct`s instead. Lastly, where exactly does your program fail? That part is missing completely from your question!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt as soon as I execute the compiled file, segmentation fault occours

Comment: In which line of the code does that happen? Either you really learn how to use a debugger now or you sprinkle output function calls throughout your code to find out.

Comment: BTW: I just took your code, compiled it and it ran without any errors. You really need to extract a [mcve]. Voting to close.

Comment: variable and parameter names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)`  function names should indicate what the function does and/or what it returns.   The names in the posted code are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via single blank line.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the function `rand()` is exposed by the header file: `stdlib.h`  however the posted code is missing that header file.  The `rand()` function needs a prior call to `srand()` to produce a 'random' set of values

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 10, 20.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: regarding: `void *fcfs(void *p)`  Since the posted code is not using the parameter `p`, the first line in the body of the function should be: `(void)p;`  Si milar considerations exist for `void *sjf(void *g)`

Comment: strongly suggest inserting a reasonable space: after commas, after semicolons, inside parens, inside braces, around C operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sjf(), if at1[0] is the minimum, location will never be initialized, thus the loop below could readily generate invalid addresses.

```
for(z=location;z>0;z--)
    {
        at1[z]=at1[z-1];
        bt1[z]=bt1[z-1];
        pid1[z]=pid1[z-1];
    }
```

When you run in “process mode”, it is very likely that your initial stack is zero-filled, thus the flaws in your program were hidden.   The initial thread stack may have other stale data in it.

As the comments point out, you should try and use some level of compiler diagnostic (and initiative) before SO.   Everybody is willing to help, but you are expected to develop the skills to help out too.

Comment: Thanks a ton man! @mevetes , you just saved my day. Initializing location to 0 worked out. Also I tried to debug the code into compiler but I am somewhat new to c programming and wasn't able to debug correctly, sorry for that. :)